# QString parse system variables

Tags: c++, regex, windows, qt, environment-variables

How I should parse QString, which contains system variables ?What I want:

```
QString path = "%WINDIR%\\System32\\";
QString output  = parse(path);
QDebug()<<output; \\ output is "C:\\Windows\\System32\\"
```

Comment: what do you want from output?

Comment: You can use split()..

Comment: yeah, this question is very vague :o Please state what exactly it is that you want to achieve :), what do you mean by "parse", do you want to extract each path element?

Comment: @dare I WANT output )

Comment: @code_fodder yes, I want to find every system variable (in mask "%*%") in QString and retrive with getenv("var")

Comment: Portable or not? On Windows, use [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265.aspx). On other systems, environment variables probably aren't between `% %`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
// Untested
QString parse(QString str)
{
    int pos = 0;
    QRegExp rx("%([^%]+)%"); // Match env var between two '%'
    rx.setMinimal(true);
    while((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1)
    {
        // Replace env var
        QString capture = rx.cap(1);
        QString replacement = getenv(capture.toAscii());
        str.replace("%" + capture + "%", replacement);

        // Skip env var + two '%'
        pos += rx.matchedLength() + 2;
    }
    return str;
}

QString path = parse("%WINDIR%\\System32");
```

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocessenvironment.html#systemEnvironment

Comment: Right, as Marek R said you could replace `getenv(capture)` by `QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment().value(capture)` to stay 100% Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you looking for. Please try this

```
QString windir = getenv ("WINDIR"); // Expanded
if (windir.isEmpty()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Generator requires WINDIRto be set\n");

}    
windir += "\\System32";
qDebug()<<windir;
```

Comment: I do not know which variable will be there, there may be a few or non-existent

Comment: I think you want "output: C:\\Windows\\System32" ? Can you please let me know, which variable you thinking about and why and what will be the expected output ?

Comment: I need to run QString, find all variables and replace them to getevn(sysvar);